# I have updated android apk on google but getting "violating the Permissions policy" error

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have updated android apk on google store but they are rejecting app due to  violating the Permissions policy . I have google it and found solution ,TO select appropriate core functionality from list. I did same and again update apk but getting same response from google. [I have got this email from google when i select the core functionalty "Default Phone handler"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kH04h.png.)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kH04h.png.)

Also some article suggest to add “uses-permissions” tags to AndroidManifest.xml .But I didn't have manifest file .So, are these tags are required for every plugin? and can we add these permissions in config.xml file? 
Can you please suggest what was wrong here?

Comment: What plugins are you using??

Comment: I have used @ionic-native/call-log to perform outgoing and to get call logs

Comment: Is it asking for permission when you use application?

Comment: Yes, when i install apk in device it ask for permissions first to get the call logs.

Comment: Check your AndroidManifest.xml file located at:
`yourProjectRoot/platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` for permissions.

Comment: Here is my AndroidManifest.xml file's uses-permission . It has already uses-permission tag for call-logs and process-outgoing-calls.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

Comment: Is there any other permission needed for core functionality issue?

Comment: Do you have any other plugins? Please run command `cordova plugin list` and add output to your question.

Comment: These are the plugins:
cordova-plugin-calllog 1.2.2 "CALLLOG"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.1.19 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"